# How to print absolute value from list of negative valued tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list that have tuples with negative values say like this

```
vect=[(-x*3,-y*2) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [1,5,6]]
```

and i want to print the list with its absolute values like

```
[(6, 2), (6, 10), (6, 12), (9, 2), (9, 10), (9, 12), (12, 2), (12, 10), (12, 12)]
```

but i tried to get an output but got an error that

> TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'tuple'

So I need a help or suggestions regarding this problem.

Comment: It's good you've posted the error, but you haven't posted the code that produces the error...

Comment: `[(abs(x), abs(y)) for x, y in vect]` or `[tuple(abs(x) for x in tup) for tup in vect]`

Comment: Thanks this is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it):

```
[(abs(i[0]), abs(i[1])) for i in vect]

# [(6, 2), (6, 10), (6, 12), (9, 2), (9, 10), (9, 12), (12, 2), (12, 10), (12, 12)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

**Ex:**

```
vect=[(-x*3,-y*2) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [1,5,6]]
print([map(abs, i) for i in vect])     #Python3 --> print([list(map(abs, i)) for i in vect])
```

**Output:**

```
[[6, 2], [6, 10], [6, 12], [9, 2], [9, 10], [9, 12], [12, 2], [12, 10], [12, 12]]
```